# Drawing App - Changing Cursor by clicking on Tool

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, cursor

I am working on a Canvas Drawing App, I'm trying to make my cursor change to the image of the drawing tool that is active while drawing on the canvas. I think i have the correct code, but it isn't working so evidently something is wrong. Thank you for any tips.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tools col-md-2">
<div>
    <input type="image" class="active" src="./assets/imgs/tools/brush.png" id="brush"
           onclick= "setLine();"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="image" class="circ" src="./assets/imgs/tools/circle.png" 
               onclick="setCircle();" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="image" src="./assets/imgs/tools/rectangle.png" 
               onclick="setRectangle()" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="image" src="./assets/imgs/tools/eraser.png" 
               onclick="setEraser()" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="image" src="./assets/imgs/tools/bucket.png" 
               onclick="setFill()" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="./assets/imgs/tools/undo.png" onclick="undoBoard()" />
    </div>


    <div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function setLine(){
    shape = SHAPE_TYPE.LINE;
    $('#Draw').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/imgs/tools/cursor_brush.png) 0 130, auto');
}
function setCircle(){
    shape = SHAPE_TYPE.CIRCLE;
    $('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/imgs/tools/cursor_circle.png) 0 0, auto');
}
function setRectangle(){
    shape = SHAPE_TYPE.RECTANGLE;
    $('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/imgs/tools/cursor_rectangle.png) 0 0, auto');
}
function setEraser(){
    console.log("i erase");
    shape = SHAPE_TYPE.ERASER;
    $('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/imgs/tools/eraser.png) 10 29, auto');
}
function setFill(){
    shape = SHAPE_TYPE.FILL;
    $('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/imgs/tools/bucket.png) 30 120, auto');
}
```

Comment: your last ```<div>``` should be for closing the first one, right? Change the last one to ```</div>```. Do you have any errors in your browsers Javascript console?

Comment: Hi Jserodio, yes that open div is supposed to be there I didn't include the entire code, the div closes after the colorpicker which is below the code I posted in my version. The only error that is popping up is: "bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery" I have a library loaded so I don't know why this error is here

Comment: Ok, it seems that the problem is related to the jQuery library not loading. If you didn't, you should download jQuery library, and add this: ```<script src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>```  **before** the ```<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>```.

Comment: I already had a library downloaded I just didn't have it before the bootstrap src, so thank you that fixed the error. My cursors still do not work though :(

Comment: No problem, we are here to help. What do you mean by "they don't work"? Do you mean that the CSS is not working, like not showing the right images?

Comment: when I click on the tool the image (for that cursor) does not show

Comment: Do the images load if you check the network tab in the console (F12)? If they do; I noticed you're using  $('#Draw') in one place and $('.canvas-boards') for the others. The cursor need to be set on the top canvas (not shown in the current code).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your assistance, I figured out the issue!! the images were too big that I was using! they had to be 128px x 128px exactly, which is a pretty stupid solution for a painful problem. I've also figured out how to load the images on click by ID which I'll post below for anyones reference. Thanks again!

//HTML

```
<div id="brush">
            <input type="image" class="active"  src="./assets/imgs/tools/brush.png" id="brush"/>
        </div>

        <div id="circle">
            <input type="image" class="circ" src="./assets/imgs/tools/circle.png" />
        </div>
```

//JAVASCRIPT

function setCursor(id) {
    console.log("init.js: setCursor(): id: " + id);

```
switch (id) {
    case 'brush':
        shape = SHAPE_TYPE.LINE;
    break;
    case 'circle':
        shape = SHAPE_TYPE.CIRCLE;
    break;

}

console.log("image path: " + 'cursor_' + id + '.png');
```

$('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/imgs/tools/cursor_' + id + '.png) 0 130, auto');
   // $('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/imgs/tools/brush.png) 0 0, auto');
}